# Highlighting same string in code blocks on selection of a string

Tags: feature-request, code-block

This is a feature request for SO sites. I would like to have highlighting of all strings which match the selected string in code examples.

A number of IDEs and editors have a facility where if I select a string in the code, it highlights all matching strings. For example, with Notepad++, if I'm editing any file, and I select a word (using double-click), then it finds all of the matching words elsewhere in the document.

[image: Example of highlighting from Notepad++]

I would find this useful when looking at code to find all usages of a particular identifier. Please note that I'm not asking for semantic highlighting, just that all matching strings get hightlighted. It should, however, be restricted the code blocks. Notepad++, does this highlighting in plain text files.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on Stack Overflow? Meta is for discussing Stack Overflow, not for asking programming questions.

Comment: And how do you envisage this would work? You go to a post on a SE site, doubleclick a word in any syntax-highlighted code snippet? Does the word light up in *all* code snippets in all posts on that page?

Comment: @Oded: he's a 17k user on SO, I'm assuming he meant this as a feature-request for SE sites. :-)

Comment: @oded Yes, it's a feature request. I added the tag feature-request and everything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure if I want *all* code snippets on that page, but just one would do for me.

Comment: Sorry about that - it just doesn't read like it has _anything_ to do with SO.

Comment: @oded no worries. Added an explanatory line.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that folks are posting snippets that are too long?

Comment: @arjan not necessarily, even in a four line code snippet you can have three or four usages of an identifier. And people *do* post code which is too long.

Comment: +1 This would be coolness.